# How to instantiate different versions of InternetExplorerDriver - Selenium 2?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

just wondering how I can instantiate different versions of InternetExplorerDriver.

That's how I can create a IE driver:

```
WebDriver ieWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

but I am not able to differentiate between IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows only supports installing a single IE version. Although some hacks exist to run multiple versions, I'm pretty sure you won't get them working with WebDriver (although I'd love to be proven wrong).

In your shoes, I would probably set up a Windows VM for each version you want to test and use RemoteWebDriver to talk to them.

Comment: yeah I was planning to have multiple VMs with different IE installations. Programmatically how can I invoke the different IE versions using RemoteWebDriver?

Comment: Your code would need to know what server has which IE version, and then instantiate RemoteWebDriver with the correct URL.

Comment: Modern.IE website lets you download VM images with various versions of IE installed https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can. DesiredCapabilities have a public method which you can use:

```
this.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
this.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "8");
this.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WINDOWS");
```

I've written extension methods to make it easier to instantiate any version by this call:

```
DesiredCapabilities internetExplorer8 =
                          DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer().SetVersion("8");
IWebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumHubUrl, internetExplorer8);
```

This really makes sense if you use RemoteWebDriver and have a Selenium2 Grid/Hub set up with multiple nodes, e.g. multiple virtual machines each having a different version of Internet Explorer and each being a node connected to the hub.

And the extension:

```
public static class DesiredCapabilitiesExtension
{
    public static DesiredCapabilities SetBrowserName(this DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities, string browserName)
    {
        // make sure the browser name is lowercase
        desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, browserName.ToLowerInvariant());
        return desiredCapabilities;
    }

    public static DesiredCapabilities SetVersion(this DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities, string version)
    {
        desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, version);
        return desiredCapabilities;
    }

    public static DesiredCapabilities SetPlatform(this DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities, string platform)
    {
        // make sure the platform is case sensitive, uppercase to make it work
        desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, platform.ToUpperInvariant());
        return desiredCapabilities;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seems to work. When I tried setting the version, the grid is unable to locate any version of IE. Although its forwarding the session with the version number but it is unable to locate the browser with right version and throws a exception that its not able to find a browser with these capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate different versions, you can set the version using capability.setVersion to the required version number. At the same time, while starting the node, you need to add the following parameters in the command line:

-browser "browserName=internet explorer,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS, version=8"

For supporting multiple versions at the same node, you can use "-browser" multiple times.

Comment: It's essential to set the browser flag on node startup otherwise the grid won't find the desired version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

However, the latest IE supports "browser mode" - just press F12 and choose the browsing mode.
AFAIK it works quite well - at least compared to IE8 and IE7.
I'm curious if it can be accessed by javascript and changed automatically in Selenium?

Comment: The simple answer is: No, you can't simulate F12 with Selenium.

The "browser mode" is not quite reliable. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11418046/1080590