# How well does IE7/8 mode in IE9 compare to actually running IE7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser

I'm trying to confirm this for work purposes so we don't need to have separate VMs to test in IE7 and IE8. I've always just used the developer tools in IE9 (F12) and changed the browser mode and document mode to do IE7 and IE8 testing.

How does this compare with actually testing in the "real" IE7 and IE8? Has anyone done a comparison or seen a write up detailing this?

I assume the IE7 and IE8 rendering engines are simply included in IE9 and it just uses those engines instead. Is there anything else I should know?

Comment: I'd be interested to know what other people thing, but we've just moved to having VMs because there were differences that the clients found running native IE8 (all plugins disabled etc) between our IE9 based IE8 mode testing.

Comment: Thanks Kieron. If you know of any specifics, can you let me know?

Comment: For us we actual styling differences, as well as behavior. Seemed like the JS engine wasn't coming out with consistent results between the two versions.

Comment: The IE10 version of this question is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14317360/841830 It'd be great if people more knowledgeable than me could post answers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I always use the real browser. I have three examples of IE 9's IE 7 mode behaving differently than the real IE 7:

1. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nU2Zp/3/) is a page that shows a transparent PNG fading out and in. In the real IE 7, you can see darkness around the edges of the image. This is not the case in IE 9's IE 7 mode.
2. Base64 images do not work in the real IE 7, but they do in IE 9's IE 7 mode. [Here](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) is a page you can test with to see for yourself.
3. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H4HkF/) is a page that shows a paragraph with `zoom: 1px;` CSS applied to it. In the real IE 7, the paragraph appears to be very small. This is not the case in IE 9's IE 7 mode.

And I have twelve examples of IE 9's IE 8 mode behaving differently than the real IE 8:

1. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PjbgV/) is a page that shows a 256px × 256px image scaled to 50px × 50px. In the real IE 8, the edges look smooth. This is not the case in IE 9's IE 8 mode.
2. CSS bug 9 from [James Hopkins' list of IE 8 bugs](http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs) (JHIE8B) does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE8Bugs/bullet-list-marker-MS-Sans-Serif.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mxnfS/)). The bug's description is "Bullet (filled disc) list-markers misrendered when using MS Sans Serif font".
3. CSS bug 15 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/imga-descenderspace.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/sNka4/)). The bug's description is "Descender space of an inline box containing an IMG (with vertical-align:baseline, and no sibling line boxes containing text) nested in an A element, is drawn only on `:hover`".
4. CSS bug 22 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/wp-content/uploads/2008/IE8Bugs/final-release/contentdynamic.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/RK8gh/)). The bug's description is "`content` property doesn’t return the value of an attribute when attribute is dynamically inserted".
5. CSS bug 31 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/liststyle/importrule-marker-inherit.html)). The bug's description is "Marker box doesn’t inherit styling from element to which its attached, when importing those style rules using @import".
6. CSS bug 38 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/overflowscroll-float-maxheight.html)). The bug's description is "Rule set that matches an element, which includes a `float` value, a `max-height` value, and an `overflow` value of `scroll`, triggers complete page blankness (forced Standards Mode), or Compatibility View fallback".
7. CSS bug 56 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/dynamicstackingcontext.html)). The bug's description is "Stacking context of relatively-positioned descendant (with lower stacking level than it’s containing block) isn’t re-calculated on ascendant `:hover` (or `:active`) when stacking level of containing block is reset to reflect default back-to-front order in document tree".
8. CSS bug 57 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/textdecoration-visibilityhidden.html)). The bug's description is "Inline element with `visibility:hidden` which *either* immediately precedes parent’s end-tag *or* immediately follows parent’s start-tag *and* immediately precedes parent’s end-tag, prevents `text-decoration` values of `underline` and `overline` being applied to the line box".
9. CSS bug 60 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/anon-tablecell_textselect.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/VWqCW/)). The bug's description is "Text inside an anonymous table object equivalent to a `table-cell` element isn’t selectable".
10. CSS bug 62 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/overflow_transparency-bleed.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NjQcs/)). The bug's description is "An element which is semi-transparent and whose contents are clipped (`overflow:hidden` applied to parent) when it overflows it’s parents box, experiences a 1 pixel transparency-related bleed along the outside edges that provide boundaries for the overflow".
11. CSS bug 65 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/background-image_first-child.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/MC23a/)). The bug's description is "When a `background-image` is applied to the `:first-child` pseudo-element, a different `background-image` applied to its associated element does not display".
12. JavaScript bug 1 from JHIE8B does not affect IE 9's IE 8 mode ([test case](http://www.domnodes.org/ie8/ie8test.html), [alternate test case](http://jsfiddle.net/DmuuB/)). The bug's description is "Utilising `querySelectorAll` within a statement that `break`s out of a `for` loop, triggers a full program crash.".

It is somewhat inconvenient having to have multiple virtual machines, but [at least they're free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575), and they work with VirtualBox, too.

---

**EDIT 1 (2012-08-21 19:40:46Z):** Added an example of IE 9's IE 8 mode behaving differently than the real IE 8.

**EDIT 2 (2012-11-16 08:11:42Z):** Updated the link in the first example of IE 9's IE 7 mode behaving differently than the real IE 7 and added the third example.

**EDIT 3 (2012-11-22):** Added eleven examples of IE 9's IE 8 mode behaving differently than the real IE 8.

Comment: Great, thanks for the examples, info and the link to the VPC images - great find! That is really awesome; Microsoft is so thoughtful!

Comment: Just released IE10 preview does not include limit on the number of CSS files it can use, unlike previous version of IE, http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading And the browsers modes in IE 10 do not emulate that limit.

Comment: Much appreciated; it's nice to have these suspicions confirmed.

Comment: Just to add to that answer. I've recently tested and IE 10 renders web fonts correctly in all browser modes, when their real counterparts don't even support them.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Nick's answer, here are two more examples of IE9 in IE7 mode behaving differently than the real IE 7:

1. localStorage works in IE9-in-IE7-mode but not in IE7.
2. sessionStorage works in IE9-in-IE7-mode but not in IE7.

Makes you wonder how many other web APIs implemented in IE9 will work in IE9-in-IE7-mode...

Answer (score 1):

In IE10, there seems to be a series of very similar issues, that make the browser and document modes unfit for reliable testing.

Many filters that do work in IE 7 and IE 8, do not work in the document and browser modes.