# IE9 in IE7 Compatibility Mode renders data URIs in css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, data-uri, ie-compatibility-mode

I'm testing a site in IE9 and using the compatibility mode to test in IE7 standards mode

few tweaks and everything is looking fine in IE7

However, I've noticed that all of the css is using data uris to images (you know the base64 fun of image inclusion). Which is fine and dandy.

However, IE7 doesn't support data URIs does it?! So why does IE9 in IE7 mode display them just fine?! If this is correct then IE9's compatibility mode is pretty useless for a complete IE7 test.

Am I correct?

Comment: Seeing the same thing really confusing me after all I just read about how it wont work and you might have to use this bizarre MHTML which I want to avoid and it looks fine.

Comment: Yeah I looked into MHTML too. I actually set up an online site for converting images to base64 and MHTML (base64me.com)

But in the end I just ended up using hard links to images.

But in short, IE7 Compatibility mode in IE9 does display base64 images in css, IE7 does not (as I created a Vista virtual machine for IE7 testing)

Comment: You are correct. For more information, see [my answer][1] to [this question][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11418046/937084
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10249454/937084

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that IE9 compatibility mode is not equal to IE7 (just compatible) and should not ever be used to test stuff for IE7. Do not depend on it.