# Need to test Print functionality for IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, print-preview

I am creating CSS (for printing) for my website and need to test my results.

Now at this point, creating CSS for print has been the easy part but testing it in IE8 through a print preview is becoming harder.

I have a Mac and Win8 machine and I'll be thankful if anyone of you can point me in a direction through which I can get hold of an IE8 browser and test the print preview functionality.

I did install IETester but its print preview is kinda messed up, as I guess it's only for rendering the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [ModernIE](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) you can download virtual machines created by Microsoft for almost any relevant IE version out there.

Answer (score 0):

guessing you have IE10. push F12 around the middle of the window pane that opens you can select browser mode to use as IE8

Comment: That won't help him because it's not rendered natively, some quirks are removed, some things work that originally didn't, etc.

Comment: it works just fine for me you can select to use IE8 document mode.

Comment: @Zeeba what they means is that the developer tool `browser modes` do not work the same as a real browser, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249454/how-well-does-ie7-8-mode-in-ie9-compare-to-actually-running-ie7-8/11418046#11418046 that is why you get services such as http://www.modern.ie/ and http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Yes, it works. But it's not 100% compatible to an original IE8 (just google for it or search on SO). And as for the printing purpose asked in this question I really think it best to try it i an original IE8 as it depends too much on the declarations used. I had a project last year where I had to style some print CSS and the differences between IE9 (in IE8 mode) and IE8 were depressing. (Although I can't currently remember if the manually changed document mode applied to the printed document as well).

Comment: roger roger. might strat using moderie myself then. thanks guys.