# Selenium IE switch document.documentMode

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, document, mode

Just a short question. How can I modify the IEs documentMode inside a given Selenium session with Java?

Background on my systems I have IE 11, but the site uses IE 7. Now I want test the web site code on a higher IE level, without changing the web code. So I think, a simple way should be adjusting the documentMode setting from outside.

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium Grid and install the desired version of IE on the node (may be a different machine) and use RemoteWebDriver with desired capabilities of that version of IE. This question is already answered at [How to instantiate different versions of InternetExplorerDriver - Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710809/how-to-instantiate-different-versions-of-internetexplorerdriver-selenium-2)